# -250 prints as 6

Tags: c

I could not identify how the following program outputs 6 and -250.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char p=-250;
    printf("%d",p);
    unsigned int p1=-250;
    printf("%d",p1);
    return 0;
}
```

Being an unsigned integer it has to output only the positive values.How does the p value outputs 6? Please help me understand.

Comment: What does your question title have to do with your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` is *not typesafe*. It prints whatever you ask it to, and `%d` says "signed integer". It is *your* responsibility to provide a varibale of matching type. Since the `unsigned char` is only 8 bits wide, the literal -250 wraps around to +6, which remains +6 when interpreted as a signed integer. Note that `char` and `short int` (and their signed/unsigned counterparts) all get promoted to `int`-types when passed via variadic arguments.

Answer (score 3):

By default, [integer numerals](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/) such as `-250` have a type `int`.  Also, negative values stores in memory in [Two's complement form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  Let calculate two's complement form of -250 (see *Making two's complement form* paragraph in wiki):

1. Positive `250` is a `11111010` (first 8 bits, leading *zeros* are omitted)
2. Complement it and get `00000101` (first 8 bits, leading *ones* are omitted)
3. Add one and get `00000110` (first 8 bits, leading *ones* are omitted)

Type conversion rules for integer types in C says that we should drop left bits to get 8-bit char.  For more details look K&R A.6.2 (well, it is for russian edition, maybe in original book it has another place).

So `unsigned char p` gets exactly a `00000110` value (`6` in decimal).  That is why you get 6 in output.

I think, you understand now why there is `-250` in second `printf` ;)

Comment: @Silver_Shost:Thanks for making me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned char` may consist only of numbers `0..255`
numbers are converted modulo `256`. So `-250` casted to `6`

You should not trust this behaviour. you should avoid overflow.

As of `p1`, it casted to unsigned int, but interpried as p1 in `printf()` because of `%d` identifier

Answer (score 2):

`p1` is `unsigned`, but the `%d` modifier treats the corresponding argument as signed, so even though in fact it is positive, it is printed as negative.

Whether a number is signed or unsigned is all about the representation that is applied, at the machine level it doesn't make a difference.